# CSS3, Angular 8, Algolia - Custom Stylesheet not overriding Widget Style

Tags: css, angular, algolia

I have an input field defined by Algolia InstantSearch v3.35.1 widget `ais-search-box` that is not responding to overrides in my custom .css file.

I show the relevant info below. Looking at the input field element using the browser debugger, it does appear that the correct widget style to override is `input.ais-SearchBox-input`. The style override also appears correct, having successfully done it in other areas.

Any ideas on what my mistake is?

Thanks,
Bob

**Snip from Browser Debugger**
[image]

**Widget Style**

```
.ais-SearchBox-input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding: 0.3rem 1.7rem;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c4c8d8;
  border-radius: 5px; }
  .ais-SearchBox-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #a5aed1; }
  .ais-SearchBox-input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #a5aed1; }
  .ais-SearchBox-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #a5aed1; }
  .ais-SearchBox-input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #a5aed1; }
```

**Override Style - tmd_basic.css**

```
.mySearchField .input.ais-SearchBox-input{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

**search.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FadeInTop} from "../../shared/animations/fade-in-top.decorator";
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite';

@FadeInTop()
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../../assets/css/tmd_basic.css']
})


export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
```

**search.component.html**

```
    <ais-instantsearch [config]="config">
        <ais-search-box placeholder="Let's find something on TMD..." class="mySearchField"></ais-search-box>
    </ais-instantsearch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below CSS.

```
mySearchField .ais-SearchBox-input{
      font-size: 14px !important;
      font-weight: 600 !important;
      padding-left: 5px !important;
      padding-bottom: 10px !important;
      background-color: red !important;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Murugan, but that didn't fix it.